# Python - passing parameter via command line to module function

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have this function defined in a `module` called `tags.py`:

```
 def lastfm_artist_to_tags(artist):

        tag_weight = {}

        result = last.get_artist(artist).get_top_tags()

        for tag in result:
            tag_weight[str(tag.item.get_name())] = str(tag.weight) 

        tag_weight = {k: int(v) for k, v in tag_weight.items()}

        return sorted(tag_weight.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

`tags.py`, as main, is sucessfully called with with:

```
print lastfm_artist_to_tags('radiohead') //note string
```

but I am trying to import the above function into my `playlist.py`, like so:

```
#playlist.py

from api.lastfm.seeds.tags import *

class hardrock(rock):
    def __init__(self,name,user):
        rock.__init__(self, name, user)

        # get tags for this artist
        tags = lastfm_artist_to_tags(str(artist))
```

and call it via command line:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    artist_name = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    artist = get_artist(artist_name) //get_artist() returns json response from Spotify API
```

by : `$ python playlist.py radiohead`

but I get the following error:

`Error: The artist you supplied could not be found`

I've tried to pass `lastfm_artist_to_tags(artist)`as well, to no avail.

folder structure:

```
playlist.py
api/
   __init__.py
   lastfm/
         __init__.py
         seeds/
              __init__.py
              tags.py
```

what am I missing here?

EDIT:

`print (artist_name)` and `print (str(artist_name))` return the same result form SPotify `API`:

```
{u'genres': [u'alternative rock', u'britpop', u'indie rock', u'neo mellow', u'permanent wave', u'pop rock', u'rock'], u'name': u'Oasis', u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4'}, u'popularity': 77, u'uri': u'spotify:artist:2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4', u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4', u'followers': {u'total': 1114541, u'href': None}, u'images': [{u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/2a8c10fe954e2038fb74251cba601a5594cc5878', u'width': 640, u'height': 640}, {u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/87d18c79bbfdb1905bb202d200e1c191afc46aa5', u'width': 320, u'height': 320}, {u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/b4d024ebb4863438b92a1b029bff7f9737263a57', u'width': 160, u'height': 160}], u'type': u'artist', u'id': u'2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4'}
{u'genres': [u'alternative rock', u'britpop', u'indie rock', u'neo mellow', u'permanent wave', u'pop rock', u'rock'], u'name': u'Oasis', u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4'}, u'popularity': 77, u'uri': u'spotify:artist:2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4', u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4', u'followers': {u'total': 1114541, u'href': None}, u'images': [{u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/2a8c10fe954e2038fb74251cba601a5594cc5878', u'width': 640, u'height': 640}, {u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/87d18c79bbfdb1905bb202d200e1c191afc46aa5', u'width': 320, u'height': 320}, {u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/b4d024ebb4863438b92a1b029bff7f9737263a57', u'width': 160, u'height': 160}], u'type': u'artist', u'id': u'2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4'}
```

Comment: From your code, `artist_name` is something you passed in from cmd line. It cannot be a JSON response. So you probably still need to edit your question to show the actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this one works:

```
print lastfm_artist_to_tags('radiohead') //note string
```

It means the function `lastfm_artist_to_tags` is working and you should seek problems elsewhere.

You probably should check whether you're indeed passing `'radiohead'` to the same function when called from another module. The easiest way is to print the parameter:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    artist_name = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    print(artist_name)   # Add this line
    artist = get_artist(artist_name)
    print(artist)        # Add this line
    print(str(artist))   # Add this line
    tags = lastfm_artist_to_tags(str(artist))
```

This should give you some useful information about what's wrong with your code. If you find all printed variables are as expected then I'm happy to have a look back.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've edited the answer upon your answer.

Comment: @data_garden I think the output you posted is still wrong because you showed a JSON object for something that's intended to be a cmd line argument. But I can see the artist name is already there and it shouldn't take too much effort to get it out and feed it to `lastfm_artist_to_tags`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Cyker 's answer, and since `get_artist()` returns `json`response, I must fix it like this:

```
tags = lastfm_artist_to_tags(str(artist['name']))
```

then `tags` will print:

```
[('britpop', 100), ('rock', 89), ('british', 61), ('alternative', 53), ('indie', 46), ('seen live', 21), ('alternative rock', 19), ('indie rock', 12), ('90s', 10), ('oasis', 9), ('pop', 7), ('Manchester', 4), ('UK', 4), ('classic rock', 3), ('Britrock', 3), ('male vocalists', 2), ('00s', 2), ('hard rock', 2), ('brit pop', 2), ('pop rock', 2), ('british rock', 2), ('english', 2), ('brit rock', 2), ('england', 1), ('favorites', 1), ('punk', 1)]
```